# Svelte: The formatter auto closes tags which are empty "<div/>"

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, svelte, prettier, formatter

I have installed Svelte for VScode and Prettier extension for my project. This issue appeared randomly after a week and only happens with .svelte files. On save, it formats empty `<div></div> to <div/>, or <p></p> to <p/>, or <img> to <img/>.` As you could have guessed, this is very annoying. I've looked around for a while only to come to an open thread on GitHub, which is not closed after a year. Please Help.

Comment: &nbsp; on middle

Comment: How exactly is that annoying? It's shorter and works, because it is compiled to the correct format.

Comment: @H.B., it can clutter git diffs (and make reviewing commits hard) now that he started without using the formatter. And at least I prefer thinking of the markup code in `.svelte` files as HTML code, and not XML code (self-closing non-void HTML elements is an error as far as I know). I guess it's all opinionated what you prefer, I just wanted to show that the other side exists.

Answer (score 1):

Prettier is opinionated and this [cannot be changed](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5641) to my knowledge. You get what you get.

Which is why the extension should not use it... but it does.

(You can opt out entirely by setting `svelte.plugin.svelte.format.enable` to `false`.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by enabling "Svelte Strict Mode" in settings as shown below. I hope it will help.

[image: Settings Image 1]

[image: Settings Image 2]